# Could moderators see votes in the past?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderator-tools, moderators

I was playing with the Internet Archive Wayback Machine, and noticed [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20101012040412/https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-elections). It's the `nominate moderators` item in the privilege page as of Oct 2010.

Here it is:

[image]

> - Moderators can see all data in the system, including **votes** and user profile information.

Is this true? In the past, could diamond moderators see votes? To what extent?

Comment: `Is this true? In the past, could diamond moderators see votes?` Yes, apparently.  *Trust noone.*

Comment: This probalby refers to the cumulative vote thingy that they can still see (e.g. unusual voting patterns between users)

Comment: The logical thing would be if they could see "posts with extreme votes", and then, who voted these OPs up at most. In the place of the SE, I would extend it with various heuristical rules, and of course I would log the IP of all users, all posts and all votes. Also these aren't enough to stop a really sophisticated voting freud attack, because it is an attack, but it is enough to make it too hard and risky (compared to the legal way, getting rep by writing good posts).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Diamond moderators can see the same information about votes as you can.

In addition, diamond mods can see *voting in the aggregate, between users.*  This is necessary to identify voter fraud.  This ability to see voting patterns has been in place for as long as I have been a mod, although the tools have improved.

There is (and has been) no other voting information that is available to the mods, including information about individual votes.  Mods cannot see who voted for whom on individual posts.

Comment: By voting in aggregate between users, is that data like: Alice has upvoted Bob 999 times and downvoted 3 times?