# Can moderators see who downvotes their answers in main sites (not meta)?

Tags: support, voting, moderators

Hypothetical situation:

A moderator of a site posts a terrible answer in the main (not meta) site they are a moderator of.

Can they see the identities of people who downvote it?

Comment: moderators can't see who votes anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find that one because it mentions "developers" and "admins", not moderators.

Comment: The duplicate was about staff, not moderators. Reopened. There's probably one about mods already but that wasn't it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts) cc @Catija - Is this one a bit better?

Comment: @Spevacus yeah! That looks a lot better as a duplicate target.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Seems a reasonable question and the linked duplicate does not focus on moderators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Upvotes and downvotes are anonymous, even moderators can't see who did them.  They can see *some* information (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218120/798831)) to help them identify voting fraud, but otherwise no.

Comment: It's very easy for moderators to use those tools to work out who's downvoting what, especially if the downvotes happen rapidly after a question or answer has been posted